# Develop a custom media player on iPhone

Tags: ios, customization, media-player

I'm interested in developing a Custom Media Player on iPhone. Can you give me a basic idea to start with, I would like to know the libraries / API's which supports to develop my own player. My custom media player has to play from local hard disk, and as well as it has to stream over network. Can you please help me out to give a start in right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [AVFoundation.Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008072), [MediaPlayer.Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006952).

Here are the sample code for,

[Music player](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845)

[Movie Player](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html)